# Prove or disprove: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of square matrix T then so is $\bar\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I think this is true.
I know that complex eigenvalues come out as conjugate pairs, but can't think of a formal proof. any lead?

Comment: So $T$ is complex matrix?

Comment: If the entries of the matrix are real, then the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are real, and complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients are always in conjugate pairs.

Comment: This is not true: Consider $\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}$. But read the comments above and there's your solution.

Comment: Thanks Mathematician42. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the characteristic equation of a (real) square matrix $A$ is given by $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients in $\lambda$ whose roots are the eigenvalues of $A$. A result that follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, is that the roots in a complex polynomial comes in conjugate pairs, from which your result follows.